# An item with the same key has already been added...ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

While trying to submit a form with file upload/multiple file upload/form fields/checkbox I get the above error. I have gone through various resources on SO but could not identify the problem. Here's my stack trace below:

```
[ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added.]
   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource) +52
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) +10925834
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) +10
   System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions.ToDictionaryFast(TValue[] array, Func`2 keySelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer) +209
   System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext.get_PropertyMetadata() +201
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperty(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) +387
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindProperties(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexElementalModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Object model) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +2541
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +633
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +494
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +199
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1680
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +94
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +559
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1c(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +82
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +105
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +588
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__14(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +65
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +484
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +151
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState, BeginInvokeDelegate`1 beginDelegate, EndInvokeVoidDelegate`1 endDelegate, TState invokeState, Object tag, Int32 timeout, SynchronizationContext callbackSyncContext) +106
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +446
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

I properly went through my model and my ViewModel, I didn't find any duplication in properties. Here's my ViewModel:

```
public class ArticlesViewModel
{
    public ArticlesViewModel()
    {
        Teams = new List<TeamVM>();            
    }

    public string gameName { get; set; }

    public List<TeamVM> Teams { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Article Content")]
    public string articleContent { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime date { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Article Title")]
    public string articleTitle { get; set; }

    [ValidateFile]
    [Display(Name = "FeaturedImage")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase featuredImage { get; set; }

    [ValidateFile]
    [Display(Name = "Picture Gallery Image(s)")]      
    public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> picturePath { get; set; }

    // properties for the articles, game, gallery and teams respectively              
    public gallery mgallery { get; set; }
    public TeamVM teams { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the controller action for the viewmodel:

```
namespace TeamBuildingCompetition.Areas.Admin.Controllers
{
    public class ArticlesController : BaseAdminController
    {
        // GET: Admin/Articles

        TBCDBEntities db;

        public ArticlesController()
        {
            db = new TBCDBEntities();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ArticlesViewModel model = new ArticlesViewModel();
            var teamList = (from p in db.teams
                         select new TeamVM()
                         {
                             teamID = p.teamID,
                             TeamName = p.teamName,
                             IsSelected = p.IsSelected
                         });
            model.Teams = teamList.ToList();

            ViewBag.gameList = new SelectList(db.games, "gameID", "gameName");          
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ArticlesViewModel model)
        {            
            try
            {
                // Get the featured file name
                string featuredFileName = Path.GetFileName(model.featuredImage.FileName);

                // Get the featured file path
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), featuredFileName);

                // Get the path that will be saved into the database
                string imgDBPath = "~/Content/Upload/" + featuredFileName.ToString();

                // Save the featured images to the folder
                model.featuredImage.SaveAs(path);              

                // Declare the picture gallery file path names
                var getFileNames = "";
                var getGalleryPath = "";
                var getGalleryImgPath = "";      

                // Iterate through each file in the collection                
                foreach (var item in model.picturePath)
                {                    
                    getFileNames = Path.GetFileName(item.FileName); // Get the file names
                    getGalleryPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Upload"), getFileNames); // Get the file paths
                    getGalleryImgPath = "~/Content/Upload/" + getFileNames.ToString(); // Get the file path to be stored in the database                    

                    item.SaveAs(getGalleryPath); // Save the each file in the upload directory
                }

                // Map article properties with values
                article objArticle = new article
                {
                    featuredImage = imgDBPath,
                    articleTitle = model.articleTitle,
                    articleContent = model.gameName,
                    date = DateTime.Now,
                    lastupdated = DateTime.Now
                };

                // Map gallery properties with values
                gallery objGallery = new gallery
                {                    
                    gameID = model.mgallery.gameID,
                    teamID = model.teams.teamID,
                    picturePath = model.picturePath.ToString()
                };

                // Insert the article/gallery picture into the database
                objBs.articleBs.Insert(objArticle);
                objBs.galleryBs.Insert(objGallery);

                TempData["Msg"] = "Created Successfully!";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Entity:'{0}' Property: '{1}' Error: '{2}'",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                        validationError.PropertyName,
                        validationError.ErrorMessage));
                    }
                }

                //throw new Exception(string.Format("Failed saving data: '{0}'", sb.ToString()), dbEx);
                TempData["Msg"] = sb.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever I remove `ArticlesViewModel model` from `public ActionResult create(ArticlesViewModel model)` of the controller, I get null reference error.

Comment: public List<TeamVM> Teams { get; set; } and public TeamVM teams { get; set; } looks suspicious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have both

```
public List<TeamVM> Teams { get; set; }
```

and

```
public TeamVM teams { get; set; }
```

While this is valid C#, you have two properties with the same name (if you don't take case into account).

Just change their names.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me in my situation